# Image covers text in TextView

Tags: android, html, image, textview

I have a `TextView`, where I add data from

```
Spanned htmlSpan = Html.fromHtml(html, p, null);
```

Where `p` is `URLImageParser`. It all works great, but I encountered a problem. Firstly, in the `TextView` the text displays from `htmlSpan` and after some time images appear and it totally covers my text. How can I avoid this problem?

This is my screenshot:

[image: Screenshot Problem]